# Как создать массив временных значений в Oracle DB?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Хочу сделать набор значений, например:

```
1, "Иванов", "Иван", "Иваныч"
2, "Петров", "Петр", "Петрович"
3, "Сидоров", "Сидор", "Сидорович"
```

И сохранить их куда-нибудь, чтобы потом использовать в запросе.

В SQL Server я бы для этого создал временную таблицу и сделал `select into` в нее. В Oracle не знаю, что для этого используют. Нагуглил про объект типа table, попробовал нечто такое:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
    type rec is record 
        (
            id number(16,0),
            code varchar2(25 char),
            status varchar2(100 char),
            descr varchar2(256 char),
            flag number(1,0)
        );
    type statuses is table of rec;
    sts statuses;
begin
    insert into sts (id, code, status, descr, flag)
    values (1, 'ERROR', 'Ошибка запроса', 'Ошибка запроса', 1);
    
    --select id, code, status, descr, flag bulk collect 
    --into sts from dbo_statuses;
end;
```

Вот то, что закомментировано, то работает. А то что не закомментировано дает ошибку "таблица или представление пользователя не существует".

Как вообще мою задачу в Oracle-стиле решить?

Comment: Вообще зависит от целей. наиболее правильным решением было бы вообще обойтись без таблицы, ибо 90% желаний делаются одним запросом без всяких хранимых процедур и временных таблиц. Но если действительно очень надо то есть и временные таблицы https://www.sql.ru/blogs/oracleandsql/1373

Comment: А если *потом использовать в запросе* - это в ОДНОМ запросе, так и CTE достаточно.

Comment: Цель я в начале указал. Нужен набор значений, с которым можно было бы работать как с таблицей. В этом наборе - полный список статусов. У людей, которые запрос будут запускать, есть таблица со статусами. Свой набор я хочу соединить с этой таблицей, понять, каких у них не хватает, и вставить им недостающие.

Comment: @Akina сте-не сте, проблема в том, что я не знаю тут как этот набор получить. Он должен быть как значение переменной, грубо говоря. int a = 5; и эту пятерку потом можно получить через a. А тут надо, чтобы вместо пятерки была а-ля таблица или что тут в оракле есть вместо этого. У меня неоткуда эти статусы выбирать референсные, я их руками хочу сохранить во что-то. Во что - не знаю, поэтому и спрашиваю.

Comment: Таблица, таблица... а получать через соответствующий запрос SELECT. Ну какая разница, как выглядит обращение - как `a` или как `(SELECT myvar FROM mytable WHERE varid = 123)`?

Comment: @Akina можно отдельный ответ с примером кода? Создайте "набор" данных как я писал и покажите его соединение с таблицей с аналогичными полями.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё правилно, только:

- чтобы использовать в запросе надо объявить либо на уровне схемы, либо в пакете
- вместо `insert ... into` значения можно присвоить либо запросом
  `select ... bulk collect into ...`, либо конструкторами

Простейший [воспроизводимый пример](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9613889030eb25c49845b4236b78df31):

```
create or replace type rec force is object (
    id number, code varchar2(16 char), status varchar2(32 char));
/
create or replace type statuses is table of rec;
/
var rc refcursor
declare
    sts statuses := statuses ();
begin
    sts :=  statuses (
        rec (1, 'ERROR', 'Ошибка запроса'),
        rec (2, 'FATAL', 'Ошибка непонятная'));
    open :rc for select * from table (sts);
end;
/
```

Результат:

```
        ID CODE             STATUS                          
---------- ---------------- --------------------------------
         1 ERROR            Ошибка запроса                  
         2 FATAL            Ошибка непонятная
```

Comment: @Shebbyman Если предложенный ответ вам не помог, оставте короткий комментарий. Я могу улучшить приведенный в ответе пример, чтобы более доступно показать путь решения.

Comment: я извиняюсь, еще не успел проверить. В тот день задачу доделал "руками", без автоматизации, а потом появились другие. На днях попробую ваше решение и тогда напишу, получилось или нет.

Comment: @Shebbyman Уже прошло более полугода, неужели не удалось попробовать?

Comment: да я каждый раз как думаю о том, чтобы зайти на стек и задать вопрос по ораклу, сразу вспоминаю вас и этот вопрос, так что даже неудобно становится) Тогда в итоге то ли отпала необходимость, то ли как-то по-другому сделали, я даже не помню где это было нужно, чтобы попробовать это туда приделать. Но сейчас просто в отрыве от задачи попробовал запустить, пишет недостаточно привилегий, а предполагался способ без заморочек. Просто, грубо говоря, массив в памяти, который будет существовать на время запроса и с которым можно будет свериться разово.

Comment: @Shebbyman Добавил ссылку на фиддле, чтобы убедить вас в работоспособности предложеного решения (на фидле выделяютс минимальные привилегии). Почему вы считаете, что мой ответ не отвечает на ваш вопрос? Ведь а) _предполагался способ без заморочек_, так и есть; б) _массив в памяти, который будет существовать на время запроса и с которым можно будет свериться разово_, предложенное решение это и делает.

Comment: У меня не работает, пишет ORA-01031: привилегий недостаточно. Но поскольку мне уже и не надо как бы, я просто отмечу ответ решением, может кому поможет.

Comment: _пишет ORA-01031: привилегий недостаточно_, повидимому вам не дали привилегию - создавать пользовательские типы. Это ошибка администраторов БД, вам к ним надо обратится.